# 20.04 Desktop for pi missing from rpi imager and ubuntu for pi downloads

Tags: raspberrypi

i am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on a raspberry pi 4 8GB. the rpi imager does not give me the option for 20.04 Desktop. It shows Ubuntu 21 Desktop, and many 20 Server options. I want 20.04 Desktop.

I have tried downloading the 20.04 .iso and using the "use custom" .img option in rpi imager but the pi wouldn't even boot up with that written to the micro sd card.

I have followed the instructions in a lot of articles and videos that point me toward the ubuntu downloads > ubuntu for IoT > ubuntu for raspberry pi 2, 3, 4 > ... and then the articles all show that there is a 20.04 option but i can only see the 21.04 Desktop option.
so now i have installed 20.04 ubuntu server and i am trying to install the Desktop from there, but i ran into some errors that are outside of my scope.

namely,

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` gave errors, saying failed to fetch some archives

trying to install tasksel gave the same errors, and said it was a temprorary failure resolving ports.ubuntu.com

how can i install Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on my raspberry pi 4?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 is too old.

The earliest release of Ubuntu Desktop that is designed to be compatible with Raspberry Pi is 20.10 (which is EOL). That is why you're offered only 21.04. If you want LTS, you must wait until 22.04, only eight months away.

The other "articles" you mention are likely installing Ubuntu Server (not Ubuntu Desktop), and then bolting a GUI on top. For many folks, that method provides an adequate desktop experience. Ubuntu Server has worked on Pi for many years.